# Как дописать условие для скрипта добавления пользователей ВК в список скрытых друзей?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт для добавление пользователей ВК в список скрытых друзей:

```
function adder(user,list,add,st) {
    var o = user;

    o[6] = parseInt(o[6]);

    add ? (o[6] & 1 << list || (o[6] += 1 << list)) : (o[6] & 1 << list && (o[6] -= 1 << list));

    setTimeout(function () {
        ajax.post("al_friends.php", {
            act: "save_cats",
            uid: user[0],
            cats: o[6],
            hash: cur.userHash
        }, {
            onDone: function(){
                var el=document.querySelector(".left_label.inl_bl");
                el.innerHTML=el.innerHTML>=1?(el.innerHTML-0)+1:1;
            }
        });
    },st||0);
}

function itr(list,add){
    function fn(start){
        for(var i=start||0,len=cur.friendsList.all.length;i<len;i++){
            adder(cur.friendsList.all[i],list,add,i*50);
        }
    }
    fn();
}
```

Данный скрипт добавляет в "скрытые" всех друзей без исключения, нужно добавить возможность оставлять выбранных. Понимаю, что нужно сделать условие, но как именно его написать не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш код, тогда можно сделать следующее:

```
function itr( list, add, list_of_visible_friends ){

    function fn( start ){
        for( var i = start || 0, len = cur.friendsList.all.length; i < len; i++ ){
            if( list_of_visible_friends.indexOf( cur.friendsList.all[i] ) == -1 ){
                adder( cur.friendsList.all[i], list, add, i*50 );
            }
        }
    }
    fn();

}
```

Т.е. передать список друзей, которые не должны быть скрыты. И проверять каждого на вхождение.
Для более точного ответа, необходимо описание структуры данных `cur.friendsList.all`.